# Insolvable, insoluble, and unsolvable

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, negative-prefixes

When speaking of a problem that has no solution, do the words *insolvable*, *insoluble*, and *unsolvable* have different shades of meaning? How do you decide which to use?

Comment: Any particular class of problem? Technical jargon will have different usage patterns for example.

Comment: I'm thinking of formal and scholarly writing in the humanities.

Comment: it should be unsolvable, not insolvable which is listed as extremely rare and I've never heard of.

Comment: @Oldcat: That's helpful. Can you tell me where insolvable is listed as rare? My Merriam-Webster doesn't mention this.

Comment: I Googled it, since I was just about to say that it wasn't a word at all.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries quotes all three, but it describes 'insolvable' as rare. The only one I would use would be 'insoluble'.

Comment: Many non-native speakers, especially Germans,  get their 'uns' and their 'ins' mixed up. I had a German colleague who used to say things like 'it is unpossible', and 'we must not use the 'inofficial method'. Our mutual American colleague was amused by this, until I pointed out that Thomas Jefferson had the same problem. The American Declaration of Independence talks about 'unalienable rights'. For such a *faux pas* to exist in a nation's first document, the German thought it hilarious.

Comment: @WS2, Although "unalienable" sounds odd to many people now, it is by no means a "faux pas." Both "inalienable" and "unalienable" date to the early 17th century, were correct in 1776, and remain correct today, and "unalienable" may have been the more common form in the eighteenth century. Also, there is evidence that Jefferson actually preferred "inalienable," and that it was John Adams who was responsible for the use of "unalienable" in the Declaration. https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/03/inalienable-unalienable.html

Comment: @Nanigashi You have resolved something which has been puzzling me for a long time. When I was studying American history at school in Britain, circa 1960, I feel sure that our teacher used to talk about "inalienable rights", with regard to the D of I. It actually came as a surprise to me, about 20 years ago to discover that the word was "unalienable". Now you have explained it - it is clear there were earlier versions which included "inalienable". So thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @Nanigashi Further - the article you linked quotes Merriam Webster. Yes, the OED also has entries for both spellings. But the entry for "unalienable" has a link to "inalienable" with an equals sign. However that for "inalienable" provides no link to "unalienable". There is no indication that either is preferred in N.America or Britain. However it does seem that "inalienable" is preferred among dictionary compilers, perhaps because of the French etymology, and the existence of the French *inaliénable*.

Comment: @WS2 I'm so glad you found that helpful. I'll just add that I think that even when discussing the D of I, many people in the U.S. would be likelier to say "inalienable" than "unalienable," though perhaps recently "unalienable" is becoming more common in discussions of the D of I or the importance of guarding personal liberties against infringement by the government. My teachers also used "inalienable" when I was in school, in the 1970s, and like you I was surprised to learn years later that the word used in the D of I was actually "unalienable" – and I went to school in the U.S.!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's any possibility of a semantic distinction in the context of *problems*. The only difference worth pointing out is that ***insoluble*** is far more common...

[image]

This isn't to say that either of the alternatives are "incorrect", though I personally don't like *insolvable* (it's just a relatively uncommon/dated negated form). And in fact there's some justification for preferring *unsolvable* simply because *insoluble* has another well-known sense...

> [**insoluble**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/insoluble) [of a substance] *- that cannot be dissolved* [often, *in water*]

...but since that sense can't possibly apply to *problems*, there can be no ambiguity here.

Comment: I'm surprised that "insoluble" is more common when it has a precise alternative meaning in chemistry and related contexts. Based on the information you've given here, I'm inclined to use "unsolvable" for problems, "insoluble" for substances, and "insolvable" for nothing at all. Thanks.

Comment: @Rebecca: That would be my inclination too. If we extrapolate the *trends* on the chart, it seems highly likely the majority will fall into line with our preference within a generation or two. They already have for [*unsolvable **equations***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insolvable+equations%2Cinsoluble+equations%2Cunsolvable+equations&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinsoluble%20equations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunsolvable%20equations%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: You'll be using 'pugilist' for 'boxer' next.

Comment: @Edwin: Hardly! The whole point of my comment was to underline the fact that my preference is in line with what one could reasonably expect to be the most common usage *in a few decades time* (even though it certainly isn't *yet*). But since [***pugilist** was supplanted by **boxer***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pugilist%2Cboxer&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpugilist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cboxer%3B%2Cc0) over a century ago, I'd have no reason to use it except in a deliberately dated/facetious context.

Comment: We might all be speaking Chinese in a few decades time (I think the apostrophe can be left out). If they can sort out my 370-year-old telomeres.

Comment: The meaning of "unsolvable" is easy to grasp without a dictionary. "Insoluble" is less so, and "pugilist" not at all. "Unsolvable" is a good, unpretentious word, and it deserves to be used.

Comment: @user53907 "pugilist" is as easy to grasp without a dictionary as, say, "giraffe". Attributing pretentiousness or intuitiveness to words which are simply less more or less commonly used is a bit silly without knowing the target audience.

Comment: @Robert: I bet there are far more native speakers who don't know/aren't exactly sure what ***pugilist*** means than don't know ***giraffe***. As to "knowing your target audience", if I were to believe [this BrE-only NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insolvable+equations%2Cinsoluble+equations%2Cunsolvable+equations&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinsoluble%20equations%3B%2Cc0) I should in principle stick to talking about ***insoluble equations*** with my fellow countrymen. But sod that - I much prefer ***unsolvable equations***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers my point was simply that vocabulary isn't intuitive or pretentious, or _hungry_, or whatever other fake assignation one wishes to impose to add fake emotional weight to a point. It's either _likely to be known_ or _not likely to be known_ based on target audience, and saying anything else just clouds things.

Comment: A great answer, and the chart is very illuminating. It's fascinating how "insoluble" drops off without a commensurate rise for "unsolvable." I'm guessing maybe the slack was taken up by "intractable," as I don't believe there was actually a decrease in the prevalence of insoluble/unsolvable problems beginning in 1960.

Answer (score 1):

A pedant will of course tell you that "insoluble" relates to "solubility", and talking about an "insoluble problem" is... bizarre at best. Alas, this seems to be one of those words that has been co-opted from its original meaning. Still, *I* wouldn't use it.

I recall seeing once, but can no longer find, that the difference between "insolvable" and "unsolvable" is whether a problem cannot be solved due to insufficient information or resources, or whether it cannot be solved because no solution is possible. I *think* "insolvable" had the latter meaning, but without being able to find the original source, I'm not sure.

Comment: And a _real_ pedant will tell you that it’s the other way around: using ‘insoluble’ to refer to problems predates the dissolution-related meaning by centuries. It is the liquid sense that has been co-opted from the original meaning. The original sense was ‘unloosenable’ (referring to knots, bonds, etc.), which was then quickly transferred figuratively to problems (which are also knots). Personally, I agree that ‘insoluble problem’ sounds odd, and I too would say ‘unsolvable problem’; but that’s current usage—nothing to do with which came first in which sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that "solve" is not the opposite of "dissolve"; a solution may be either a liquid or an answer. The negative form should depend on the meaning of the positive form, so a substance would be insoluble, but a problem would be unsolvable. However, "insoluble" sounds more erudite and is easier to say, making it doubly attractive  to most of us.

Answer (score -1):

I would think "un" would link to the person applying the word, and that "in" would be applied in universal terms, that would link to all persons. So 'unsolvable' is with respect to my frame of experience, and insolvable with respect to all. So it's "can I, or can I not solve it," or "can it, or can it not be solved?" (But that's guessing--I've been called an idiot). Curious

Comment: Hi Cordell! This is an interesting guess, however it would be mich better if you found some sources to support your answer.