# What is the term for the unstated elements within rhetoric and/or their use?

Tags: rhetoric

I've always understood that the term rhetoric specifically referred to the conveyance of some concept that is not represented at all in the literal meaning of the words used.

A few examples:
These refugees just keep crossing our borders.
*Their crossing of borders is axiomatically bad.*

If you prick us, do we not bleed?
*We are the same.*

These so-called experts think we need more supervision.
*We don't need more supervision, and their expertise is in question.*

I've just started digging into the subject of rhetoric, and found I've been very wrong in my definition, but still find the concept of that unstated component interesting.

Is there a term for it, and if so, what is it?

Comment: This sounds like **subtext**.

Comment: Are these not just implications? An implicit statement meant to be inferred from the context of the explicit statement that is made?

Comment: You would probably learn a lot by reading [the Wikipedia entry on *rhetoric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An argument with an unstated but implied premise is an *enthymeme*.

From the [Silva Rhetoricae](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/E/enthymeme.htm):

> ### Enthymeme
>
> 1. The informal method of reasoning typical of rhetorical discourse. The enthymeme is sometimes defined as a "truncated syllogism" since either the major or minor premise found in that more formal method of reasoning is left implied. The enthymeme typically occurs as a conclusion coupled with a reason. When several enthymemes are linked together, this becomes [sorites](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/S/sorites.htm).

The implicit premise itself doesn't have a dedicated term which I'm aware of, but you might call it a *enthymemetic premise* or a *suppressed premise* or even a *tacit premise* (as opposed to an *explicit premise*).

These are the kinds of [premises embedded, but hidden, in *loaded questions*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195054/word-that-describes-a-problem-that-is-missing-a-precondition/195061#195061) (in fact, they are the very thing the question is *loaded* with!).

Answer (score 0):

You might call them *assumptions*, or *presuppositions* if you are referring to something more closely related to one's mindset or worldview.

> **Assumption** *noun*
> 1 A thing that is accepted as true or as certain to happen, without proof:
> ‘they made certain assumptions about the market’
> [with clause] ‘we're working on the assumption that the time of death was after midnight’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assumption)
>
> **Presupposition** *noun*
> A thing tacitly assumed beforehand at the beginning of a line of argument or course of action:
> ‘both men shared certain ethical presuppositions about the universe’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/presupposition)

Comment: How about *implicit*  assumptions or premises?

Comment: @aparente001 *Implicit assumptions* fall under the definition of *presuppositions*, as do *premises*, *axioms* and the like.