# word for when you take things to be true without questioning or reason

Tags: single-word-requests

looking for a word that would work for when you take things to be true without questioning or reason. like the sky is blue, stealing is wrong, believing in santa, etc.

not looking for the "sheep", bigot or bias but rather the word that signifies how we just accept our life.

Comment: Related: [What is the term for the unstated elements within rhetoric and/or their use?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/360635/142322)

Comment: something along the lines of empiricism v. rationalism - deep stuff!

Answer (score 1):

[**Faith**](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/Faith) is a good one.  According to *An American Dictionary of the English Language*, by Noah Webster, (1828) the primary meaning of the word is more or less just what you describe:

> 1. Belief; the assent of the mind to the truth of what is declared by another, resting on his authority and veracity, without other evidence; the judgment that what another states or testifies is the truth. I have strong faith or no faith in the testimony of a witness, or in what a historian narrates

Normally, I would try to prove my assertions up, down and all around, but this time I think it would be more effective to just let this answer rest upon faith itself. I mean, I do not expect people to place their faith in me, but aside from *Webster's* credibility as a lexicographer, which deserves at least some amount of faith, [it is a "Very Common" word according to Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/faith), by which they mean within the top 4000 words in the language. I have faith in the notion that we all know how the word can be used, without any further need to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for the expression, **"take for granted"**? As in, "We take for granted that the sky is blue, sunshine is warm, and snow is cold."

There is also the word **"assumption."** This has a more argumentative tone. It basically means, "a belief that you have no evidence for and/or can't prove, but which you believe to be true anyway." There are 2 main types. Descriptive assumptions are beliefs about how the world is: "the sky is blue", but also more sinister and discriminatory ones like the famous, "Mexicans are all dirty murderers and rapists." Then prescriptive (a.k.a. "value") assumptions are moral and/or ethical ones: stealing is bad; we ought to all donate our organs; human life should always be valued above the lives of other organisms.

**Warning:** In everyday conversation, "assumption" usually has a negative connotation; it means you're being called out for a mistaken belief, or calling someone else out on a belief that isn't necessarily true. E.g. "Stop assuming things," means, "Stop making up beliefs/interpretations you don't have evidence for."

**Usage Notes:**

When you use "take for granted (that)," you specify what the belief is: "Having safe tap water is taken for granted in this city." "We (can) take it for granted that the sun will rise tomorrow."

When we use "assumption," it replaces the description of the belief: "You made an assumption about the tap water's safety." You can, of course, turn "assume" into a verb to describe the belief: "We assume the tap water is safe." "We (can) assume that the sun will rise tomorrow."

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those are what I am looking for. More along the lines of tradition, like we keep doing something because that is what we were taught to do and we do it without thinking about why.

Comment: Okay...that seems to be different from your initial request's example, but now you seem to be talking about "norms" (cultural and social norms) or "conventions" (as in the root of "conventional").

Answer (score 0):

Orthodox means something conforms to a belief system or a set of cultural norms, such as "stealing is wrong."

Traditional  means something that is culturally accepted, like passing down a belief in Santa.

Axiomatic refers to something that is self-evident, like "the sky is blue."