# What is the precise name for this non sequitur

Tags: rhetoric

Randomly came across an article with the title [Why Angry White America Fell For Putin](http://www.vanityfair.com/news/2016/12/why-angry-white-america-fell-for-putin) today.

Provocative title and content of the article aside, there is an obvious kind of fallacy in the title itself. A statement of the form "Why X" where the truth of X is assumed but not actually an established fact. Is there, and what is, the precise name of this non sequitur?

---

P.S. First post here. Couldn't find the rhetoric stack exchange so hope this is a good enough place for this.

Comment: Hmm. ***Loaded question***, as in "Have you stopped beating your wife"?

Comment: But it's not a question. Loaded statement perhaps. But yes loaded question is on the right track.

Comment: It is an implicit question (setting out with *Why...?*). But maybe you'd prefer *[enthymematic argument](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/195061/55623)* (where "Angry White America *did* indeed fall for Putin" is the hidden *enthymeme*).

Comment: Why on Earth would you down vote, down voter? Please tell.

Comment: I dunno, but I obviated it with an upvote. My advice is to ignore both. Forever.

Comment: Ta. Sorry down vote rage got the better of me. Ignoring forever.

Comment: Anyway, *loaded question* lead me to my answer: [Presupposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presupposition). Thanks for that.

Comment: Don't apologize. Your rage is rightly placed on the driveby downvoter, a plague on this site. Have a revenge upvote.

Comment: Sorry, stupid question here.  What's wrong with the title?  "Fell"?

Comment: Is this actually a non sequitor or a fallacious statement? Any number of books, articles, arguments, etc. state their premise before it is proved. For all I know, the article presented an argument to substantiate this statement adequately. If so, I think that just makes it the title (or thesis statement, if you will). Picking it out and calling it a fallacy as if it occurred in a vacuum seems odd.

Answer (score 2):

This does look a lot like 'begging the question' since the statement, which is yet to be expounded upon in the article, already contains the conclusion ie "they fell for it" (gullible/stupid) because of or in addition to the fact they are "angry white men" (racist and agressive).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [Begging the Question](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/begging-the-question).

As one of the comments stated, it's very similar to the statement form of a "loaded question". Assumptions are made (Angry Whites Americans fell for Putin), begging the question "Why"; which this article is happy to provide an answer for.